# Loop gets terminated without any error

Tags: c, loops

well I have been trying to write this program which accepts any number of integers until the condition is true using do while loop but the loop gets terminated even if the condition is met.I am not able to understand the flaw in my code... I would be thankful for any help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int max,min,test;
    char next;
    printf("enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&max);
    min=max;
    do
    {
        printf("enter next integer:\n");
        scanf("%d",&test);
        if(test>max)
            max=test;
        else if(test<min)
            min=test;
        printf("want to enter next number y/n\n");
        scanf("%c",&next);
    }while(next=='y');
    printf("Maximum=%d\nMinimum=%d\nRange=%d\n",max,min,max-min);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: "My code is not working" is no **specific** problem description. Details. And use a debugger.

Comment: nope... its not working  even if i mention a space between " and %c

Comment: Try `scanf(" %c", &next);`. If that doesn't fix the problem, mention your inputs. And do you have a run-time error (you have that tag) or have you got the meaning of run-time error wrong?

Comment: Also, initialise `min=INT_MAX; max = INT_MIN;` instead of making them the same.

Comment: min get initialised with value of max right?

Comment: Yes, init min to maxval and max to minval. Consider what will happen if you init `min = 0` and then an input is `10`

Comment: Then -10 gets assigned to test and since test is < min... It gets assigned to min

Comment: Sorry, yes, edited comment before you remarked, or initialise from the first input as answered below.

Comment: Sigh, I put a fully working example and a reason not to use `scanf()`, and my only response is "how to force scanf to work".

Comment: i mean cant the trailing error be fixed? i know that what you've given would work sir, but i cant understand much of what you've put up

Comment: Got it!By simply adding \n after %c this can be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int max,min,test;
    char next;
    printf("enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&max);
    min=max;
    do
    {
        printf("enter next integer:\n");
        scanf("%d",&test);
        getchar();        // added this
        if(test>max)
            max=test;
        else if(test<min)
            min=test;
        printf("want to enter next number y/n\n");
        scanf("%c",&next);
    }while(next=='y');
    printf("Maximum=%d\nMinimum=%d\nRange=%d\n",max,min,max-min);
    getch();
}
```

After taking input **test** when you are pressing **Enter** your code takes **Enter** as a **new line** character. To avoid this, take that **new line** character through *getchar()*.

Comment: Have you found now? @ch3rub7

Answer (score 1):

When reading input through `scanf()`, It will not consume return key so '\n' will remain there in `stdin` waiting to read for next `char` input. That is why your program is coming out of loop. So to avoid this problem use `getchar()` after `scanf("%d",&test);`.

Answer (score -1):

in **`else if (condition)`** you have written `test<min`, where variable `min` does not have any value. you should write

```
else if(test<max)
(
 min = test
)
```

Comment: I've assigned value of max to min right after it is scanned